Kids book about children who discover they can manipulate elements with their minds
Here's everything that I remember about it since it was a long time ago:

It was a kids book, probably middle school level
It was about kids of a younger age who find out that they can create certain elements via their mind and they bring matter together and change it into say water, or fire
They find this secret program that trains these kids and there are levels of the power, which are based on how strong of a weather event/element they can create (a tornado would be a high level, level 4)
The main character is a boy and he has one girl and one boy as his friends
They obviously end up fighting some bad guy or organization and at the end I'm pretty sure the MC makes a tornado (level 4)


Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Approximately when did you read this?  Do you recall the cover art, or the names of any characters or locations?  Was it set in a modern-type world or a mediaeval-type fantasy world?

You could improve this Story-Identification question by going through the checklists here and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

https://www.goodreads.com/list/show/131041.Elemental_Control and https://www.goodreads.com/list/show/42544.Books_with_Elemental_Magic might be useful for research.

You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Might it be The Dysasters by P.C. and Kristin Cast?


Foster Stewart knows she's different. Her life has never been "normal." Talking to plants and controlling cloud formations aren't things most seventeen year olds are into. Tate "Nighthawk" Taylor is perfect. Star quarterback and all around dreamy boy next door he never thought about his "extra" abilities. What quarterback wouldn't want night vision? That's not weird, right? It's cool!
But on the night of their first meeting a deadly tornado brings them together and awakens their true abilities - the power to control the element air. Unbeknown to Tate and Foster, they are the first in a group of teens that were genetically manipulated before birth to bond with the elements. Which truly sucks for Foster, as she has to face the fact that Dr. Rick Stewart, her beloved scientist father, betrayed her and now wants to use her and the others for his own nefarious world domination plot.
Foster and Tate must stop Dr. Stewart and his minions before he destroys their lives and the world.

This review mentions the other elements.

This book is told in the third person point of view following Foster, 18 as she and her adoptive mother, Cora gets ready to go to a high school football game to meet Tate Taylor. The second point of view is Tate Taylor, star football player at Homer High. A strong tornado came suddenly and wiped most of the town and its people. The third view is Mark who has the power to control the element water like rain is working with Matthew who controls wind and Luke who controls fire to search for Foster and Tate to bring them back to Dr. Rick Stewart. The fourth view is Eve who can control earth like earthquakes. Eve along with Mark, Matthew and Luke and eight others were genetically created by Dr. Stewart. The fifth view is Charlotte, a girl who was born Charles and loves the sea. The sixth view is Bastian who left fine food and money to be free near the sea. The seventh view is G-Pa, Tate’s awesome grandpa. From the sudden storm, Foster loses her adoptive mom Cora and Tate loses both of his parents; however, they discovered something about themselves that shocked them enough to go on the run.

Found with search terms of site:goodreads.com kids element control secret program tornado
